# Centos iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: linux, iptables, centos6, linux-kernel

I had a CentOS6.7 with OpenVZ. Now, I just uninstalled OpenVZ and start using Plain CentOS6.7. Due to some difficulties for using cPanel in OpenVZ.

I noticed one problem when install csf in my plain server. 
Error:  iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

this error comes only when using -m state option with iptables.

Message Log : FATAL: Error inserting xt_state (/lib/modules/2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/xt_state.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter

Dmesg Log : nf_conntrack: Unknown parameter `ip_conntrack_disable_ve0'

Can someone give any idea and please share some troubleshooting link if you have ?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the kernel module for the iptables state module. The kernel version that you appear to be running is for RHEL/CentOS 6.4, but you say you're running 6.7. Do you have the latest kernel version installed? Can you check that you are in fact running the 6.4 kernel (uname -r)? Can you try rebooting into a different kernel and seeing if iptables works like that? If so, and you need to use this particular kernel version, try re-installing it and seeing if it fixes the issue.

There's probably some interaction between the kernel version you're running and an old OpenVZ kernel, one of which expects symbols that the other doesn't provide, or something along those lines (although not having experience with OpenVZ I can't say this for certain, this is just from reading the error message).

Comment: When I checked in /etc/redhat-release file, it says "Centos 6.7(Final)". I haven't install/update kernel in my server. 

 Only thing I did, Just uninstalled OpenVZ